# Hadoop- Namenode is in Safemode ? why?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I encountered an issue where in the namenode logs say  "**Name node is in safe mode**" whereas the output of the command "**hdfs dfs -safemode get**" shows "**Safe mode is OFF**".

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The result you get when you throw this command on the shell:

```sh
$ hdfs dfs -safemode get
-safemode: Unknown command
```

If you want to know if HDFS  is in safemode you have to use the following command:

```sh
$ hdfs dfsadmin -safemode get
```

if you want to leave from -safemode use this command

```sh
$ hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```